# Condition as sum of hexadecimal numbers in old Pascal code

Tags: hex, pascal

I've got a very old Pascal program. At the top of the unit is a set of constants looking like:

```
feature1 = $01; 
feature2 = $02; 
feature3 = $04;
feature4 = $08; 
feature5 = $10;
```

In database there is a column represents atributes and there is a sum of above features combination. I assume it might be very usefull and even today it let us avoid complicated
conditional block, but i would like to read more about it and see more well explained examples of this type of code. So if you see something like that before i would be appreciated for links to some articles and excercises because i don't even know what i have to searching for in Google.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as bitmasks. In binary those values are 00001, 00010, 00100, 01000, 10000, so you can test for a bit with the `and` operator, eg. `if Value and feature2 <> 0 then ... (feature bit 2 was set)`.

Comment: And generally they are ORed together. Doesn't matter if you start from zero, but it does matter if you want to set feature3 and don't know if it is already set.

Comment: This is actually not the most "Pascalese" way of doing things: Pascal has a specific language feature, the `SET OF` to do the same thing (and in most compilers, SETs end up as bitfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the constants in Free Pascal

```
Program HexConstants;

Const
    (* In Pascal a hexadecimal numeric literal is indicated by
       prefixing a numeric literal with a $ *)
    feature1 = $01;
    feature2 = $02;
    feature3 = $04;
    feature4 = $08;
    feature5 = $10;

Var
    features : integer;

procedure PrintFeatureDecimalValues();
begin
    Writeln(' feature1 = ', feature1);
    Writeln(' feature2 = ', feature2);
    Writeln(' feature3 = ', feature3);
    Writeln(' feature4 = ', feature4);
    Writeln(' feature5 = ', feature5);
    Writeln('__________________________________');
end;

procedure ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features : integer);
begin
    if features = 0 then
        Writeln('No features are set');
    (* bitwise **and** to see if feature<n> bit is set *)
    if features and feature1 <> 0 then
        Writeln('Feature 1 is set');
    if features and feature2 <> 0 then
        Writeln('Feature 2 is set');
    if features and feature3 <> 0 then
        Writeln('Feature 3 is set');
    if features and feature4 <> 0 then
        Writeln('Feature 4 is set');
    if features and feature5 <> 0 then
        Writeln('Feature 5 is set');
    Writeln('__________________________________');
end;

Begin
    PrintFeatureDecimalValues;
    features := feature1 + feature3;
    ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features);
    features := feature4 + feature5;
    ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features);
    features := 0;
    ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features);
    features := feature1 + feature2 + feature3 + feature4 + feature5;
    ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features);
    (* adding to an already set feature *)
    features := feature2;
    features := features or feature4; (* adding feature4 *)
    ShowFeaturesThatAreSet(features);    
End.
```

Output:

```
feature1 = 1
feature2 = 2
feature3 = 4
feature4 = 8
feature5 = 16
__________________________________
Feature 1 is set
Feature 3 is set
__________________________________
Feature 4 is set
Feature 5 is set
__________________________________
No features are set
__________________________________
Feature 1 is set
Feature 2 is set
Feature 3 is set
Feature 4 is set
Feature 5 is set
__________________________________
Feature 2 is set
Feature 4 is set
__________________________________
```